# Calculate radius of convergence of $f(x) = \frac {\sin(z)}{z}$, for every $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to calculate the convergence radius of the function $f(x) = \frac {\sin(z)}{z}$, for every $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$. I would know how to do it if it was along $z_{0} = 0$, but I am having problems to expand it to any $z_{0}$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

To expand $ f(z) $ around $ z=z_0 $, you expand $ g(z)=f(z+z_0) $ around $0$.

$$g(z)=\frac{\sin(z+z_0)}{z+z_0}$$
$$=\frac{\sin(z)\cos(z_0)+\cos(z)\sin(z_0)}{z_0(1+\frac{z}{z_0})}$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)= \frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and can be made entire by defining $f(0)=1$, so its power series has an infinite radius of convergence everywhere in the plane.